# Partial View Validation Without JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a partial view in which there is a form. I POST this form using the PRG pattern. I am using the AjaxHelper to create my form. I also need this form to work without javascript. The problem is that when model validation fails, it always changes the url to my partial view.

```
public ActionResult PostForm(PostFormModel postFormModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SomewhereElse");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_PostForm")
        }
        else
        {
            // What do I do here?
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
return PartialView("_PostForm", postFormModel);
```

This just renders the partial view and doesn't contain any of the parent stuff.

```
return View("Index", new ParentModel() { PostFormModel = postFormModel });
```

This actually produces the correct result. It displays the parent view, but the URL is that of the partial `http://localhost:22485/Controller/PostForm`! I feel  like this is really close to the solution. What now?

Comment: Why 'return PartialView("_PostForm", postFormModel);' goes after method body? Is it misprint?

Comment: Yep, sorry. Edited formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change url, you should redirect to another action (using PRG pattern). Insert next code instead of '// What do I do here?':

```
postModelService.Save(postFormModel); //to Session or to DB
return RedirectToAction("Parent");
```

New action should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Parent()
{
    var postFormModel = postModelService.Load();
    return View("Index", new ParentModel() { PostFormModel = postFormModel });
}
```

Hope it helps.